# SQL Aggregates not executing

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run the following query on my local MySQL database. Query runs indefinitely and then cancels, although the database size is just a few MB.
The objective is to find the standard deviation of a stock over the last 30 days; with the additional condition of selecting stocks where the maximum stock price in the last 30 days is less than half at present.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

```
SELECT T1.id, FORMAT(STD(T1.price_usd),4) as a from ticker T1
INNER JOIN ticker T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
WHERE T2.price_usd < ( Select max(price_usd) from ticker where last_updated 
>= 1508550264 - (60*60*24*30) )/2 
AND
T1.last_updated > 1508550264 - (60*60*24*30) Group by ID HAVING a < 0.01;
```

Here is some sample data to clarify:

```
stock     last_updated     price_usd
amazon    12th Oct 2017    10
amazon    13th Oct 2017    20
amazon    14th Oct 2017    30
amazon    15th Oct 2017    50
google    12th Oct 2017    50
google    13th Oct 2017    20
google    14th Oct 2017    30
google    15th Oct 2017    10
```

In this example, google will be selected but not amazon, because google's latest price is less than half of its max. The second part is to calculate the standard deviation for google.

Comment: What about indexes?
Are last_updated, a and price_usd fields indexed?

Comment: Pleas create a fiddle with sample data or add the sample data here into your question. That'll be really helpful.

Comment: Here is sample data to clarify:
stock_id    last_updated      price_usd
amazon    12th Oct 2017    10
amazon    13th Oct 2017    20
amazon    14th Oct 2017    30
amazon    15th Oct 2017    50

Comment: amazon    12th Oct 2017    10
amazon    13th Oct 2017    20
amazon    14th Oct 2017    30
amazon    15th Oct 2017    50
google    12th Oct 2017    50
google    13th Oct 2017    20
google    14th Oct 2017    30
google    15th Oct 2017    10
In this example, google will be selected but not amazon, because google's latest price is less than half of its max. The second part is to calculate the standard deviation for google.

Comment: `from ticker T1 INNER JOIN ticker T2 ON T1.id = T2.id`? You are joining every record with itself? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the latest entry for a stockname (amazon, google) by ordering its records descending and taking the first result with `LIMIT`.

```
select
  stockname,
  format(std(price_usd), 4) as standard_deviation
from ticker
where last_updated > current_date - interval 30 day
group by stockname
having max(price_usd) / 2 > 
(
  select latest.price_usd
  from ticker latest
  where latest.stockname = ticker.stockname
  order by latest.last_updated desc
  limit 1
)
order by stockname;
```